# I want to display only 1 name for each

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image]

I've started this messaging system. In the image above you see that Danny has sent me 3 messages, and Bibby has sent me 2 messages. But I only want there name to be displayed once, so basically there names are like a category, so then when I click the name I get all the messages from that person?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you pulling the messages?  Example SQL statement please?  You can do this with a `GROUP BY` in the SQL.

Comment: Add a GROUP BY "SENDER" to the query you are using for displaying the list of messages.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways, *I think*, to retrieve unique records from the database,

One is by using `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM tableName
```

The other way is by using `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT Name
FROM tableName
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: Sorry i dont understand this is what i have so far

Comment: $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dm WHERE torn='$session_rand'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 $sendername = $row["fromuser"];
 
 echo '<div class="eachuser" style="background-color:#FFF; margin-bottom:1px; padding:7px; font-size:12px; text-align:center;">
 ' .$sendername. '
 </div>';
}

Comment: @user1217322 it is much better to have sample records with desired result for question like this. If you have multiple columns in your table and you want to select it all, `DISTINCT` will not help you. But there are always solutions to problems, all i need is to show sample records `:D`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * dm WHERE torn='$session_rand' GROUP BY fromuser ");
  $count = mysql_num_rows($sql); 
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  { $sendername = $row["fromuser"]; 
    echo '<div class="eachuser" style="background-color:#FFF; margin-bottom:1px;  padding:7px; font-size:12px; text-align:center;"> ' .$sendername. ' </div>'; }
```

- i wonder why you are using `class="eachuser"` and in the same time you have inner style ?

put those

```
   background-color:#FFF; margin-bottom:1px;  padding:7px; font-size:12px; text-align:center;
```

in the `eachuser` class and remove them from inside the div

Answer (score -1):

What you'd probably like to do (if you don't want to follow @JW.'s example modifying your database query), is to create an array to store the names you already displayed once and check against it at every instance of looping through the result set.

```
// the result set coming from the database - all senders
$senders = array('danny', 'danny', 'danny', 'bibby', 'bibby', 'danny', 'bibby');
// the empty array to store the already displayed senders
$displayed = array();

// loop through each sender
foreach($senders as $sender) {
   // if the sender is not in the array (therefore not yet displayed)
   if(!in_array($sender, $displayed) {
      echo $sender . "<br />";
      $displayed[] = $sender;
   }
}
```

This loop should echo back each name only once.

Comment: This is a very long process. Edit your answer, using the function `array_unique();` then I shall remove the -1

Comment: @DarylGill : The only issue with `array_unique()` is that we are talking about a result set coming back from the database, therefore we might have multiple rows of data sharing the same sender name...
@user1217322 : If you have only the sender names in the `$senders` array, you should use `$senders = array_unique($senders);` before the `foreach` loop therefore you don't have to be bothered about checking each time whether or not the name is unique.